# Why did Darkness pick the name "Darkness"?

Tags: konosuba

We understand she's embarrassed about her real name Lalatina and noble status. But was it ever explained how/why she specifically came to choose to go by Darkness of all possible names?

Comment: could be that is kinda sounds like her middle name [Dustiness](http://konosuba.wikia.com/wiki/Darkness)

Comment: because "Shadow" IGN already taken :P

Comment: Because her soul is dark with masochism.

Comment: Because chunyibo

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing confirmed, but there are a lot of possibilities.

1. Darkness is a status effect in Final Fantasy, which is also known as Blind. It makes the affected miss their attacks. So her nickname could be a reference to this.
2. It could refer to her masochism, her inner "Darkness"
3. It could be a slightly modified Dustiness. 
   Dustiness in Japanese is ダスティネス. Darkness is ダクネス.

Keeping the first and the last two katakana of Dustiness, changing the "su" ス into a similar looking "ku" ク and discarding the other two katakana, and you have Darkness.